# Hosting GRPC Service with IIS & HTTP2 (without grpc-web)

Tags: .net, iis, grpc, windows-server-2019, windows-server-2022

We would like to host our GRPC service on IIS using HTTP2 with Windows Server 2019. There seems to be conflicting/outdated information online, so I was hoping someone with more experience could provide me with an up-to-date answer:

1). Does Windows Server 2019 IIS support GRPC & HTTP2?
2). Does Windows Server 2022 IIS support GRPC & HTTP2?
3). Can a .Net Framework 4.7 app successfully make async unary grpc calls to an IIS hosted service over HTTP2? (using WinHttpHandler). 2019/2022?

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: This seems to be properly documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-6.0.  Ad 1 and 2: For ASP.NET Core on IIS you need "Windows Server 2022 Build 20348 or later". Ad 3: That won't work unless you have a windows insider build that has the right WinHttpHandler patches (see the link).

Comment: I appreciate your response! They must have updated the documentation, it used to just say "windows build X" without the Server 2022 part. Great news, thanks again.

Comment: @p.Doug did you find a way to deploy grpc in IIS and have  a client in .NET 4.7 to talk to it? Because I have exactly the same requirement.